# Using backbone and other apis

Tags: backbone.js

How would I use backbone to connect to third party apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're running into the cross domain script error. So, one solution would be to change the data format into something that works cross domain, like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  So your code becomes:

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=yellowstone+national+park&format=json&pretty=2"
});
var testModel = new TestModel({});
var test_data = testModel.fetch({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success : function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```